# How MySQL conditionnals "where clauses" work?

Tags: mysql

I was wondering how the clauses in a WHERE SQL statement is working, especially when we use "OR" conditions.

In other terms, on the statement :

```
 SELECT val1 FROM table WHERE val2 = x OR val3 = y
```

Does the search stop directly when the first condition is verified or the statement tries to read everything, just to check if other conditions are fulfilled?

If it stops as soon as one condition is fulfilled, then we should put the biggest and resources-needed clauses at the end of clauses, but if it does not we can put them wherever we want with no changes.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/where-optimization.html

Comment: ... and [Operator Precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html)

Comment: *Does the search stops directly when the first condition is verified or the statement tries to read everything, just to check if other conditions are fullfilled ?* Really - nobody knows. But in general - inner execution order matches the query text by 50% (maybe matches, maybe not). And probable relation between first and last 50%-s is not predictable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this article it is doing the short circuit.

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-or/

Answer (score 1):

I often use the metaphor of a telephone book for databases searches.

If you search for `WHERE last_name = 'Thomas'` then the fact that the book is in sorted order by last name helps improve the efficiency of your search. You can skip directly to the "T" names and within them, skip directly to "Th" names and so on.

But if you search for `WHERE first_name = 'Thomas'` the telephone book is in the wrong order. It is not sorted by first name, so you have to read the book page by page and search it the hard way.

Could you make an alternative telephone book that was sorted by first name? Yes. Then searching by first name would be efficient.

What if you search for both? Like `WHERE last_name = 'Thomas' OR first_name = 'Thomas'`

If you search using the original telephone book, you have to search the hard way because of the first_name condition.

If you search using the alternative book, you have the same problem, because a search for last name cannot use the sort order of the book.

The telephone books are meant to be an analogy for indexes in a database table. They help by maintaining a sorted list of values, so searches are more efficient. But like the telephone book, a given index can only sort one way. If you need indexes to help alternative searches, you need multiple indexes.

You can use only one or the other index for a given search.

So one solution is: do two searches, and find the union of both.

```
SELECT val1 FROM table WHERE val2 = x
UNION
SELECT val1 FROM table WHERE val3 = y;
```

This can use a different indexes for each search, then the result of each search is combined with the other.